# What's an example of a 'cheville' word in english?

Tags: meaning, expressions, poetry, loanwords

The [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cheville?s=t) word of the day is '[Cheville](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cheville?s=t)' and it explains it as such: A word or expression whose only function is to fill a metrical gap in a verse or to balance a sentence.

Can anyone give some examples of these words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible example is noted in this sonnet (the "Oh," in line 5)

> I am in need of music that would flow
>   Over my fretful, feeling finger-tips,
>   Over my bitter-tainted, trembling lips,
>   With melody, deep, clear, and liquid-slow.
>   Oh, for the healing swaying, old and low,
>   ...

[Source](http://mercureapenglish.blogspot.com/2012/01/sonnet.html): Sonnet (1928) by Elizabeth Bishop

---

In addition, the insertion of "dost" (or "do") in order to match the meter requirements is another example:

> How can my Muse want subject to invent,
>   While thou dost breathe, that pour'st into my verse

[Source](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/Poetry/sonnet.XXXVIII.html): Sonnet 38 by Shakespeare

Answer (score 1):

Most intensifiers - "very", "quite", "so", etc. - add no real meaning, and can be added or dropped at will to assist in scansion.

In addition, declamatory introductions such as "Oh", "Lo", etc. can fill the same role; they're a bit less common in modern usage, however.

Answer (score 1):

Stated, the normal usage is in verse/lyrical sense

So in the modern age a more appropriate 'Cheville' example would be:

(no cheville)
you know how it feels
when the car has no wheels

(Cheville)
you know how it - really feels
when your car 'ain't got' no wheels

It has no real obvious purpose other then enforce, empower and/or change the lyrical flow of the verse to match maybe a beat and/or compensate for missing "glue" to match the previous statement/rhyme.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple sentences from [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheville):

> 1905, Robert Louis Stevenson, The Art of Writing:
>
> - The genius of prose rejects the cheville no less emphatically than the laws of verse; and the cheville, I should perhaps explain to some of my readers, is any meaningless or very watered phrase employed to strike a balance in the sound.
>
> 1910, Patrick Weston Joyce, English as we speak it in Ireland, chapter 5
>
> - The practice of using chevilles was very common in old Irish poetry, and a bad practice it was; for many a good poem is quite spoiled by the constant and wearisome recurrence of these chevilles.
>
>   'They met with an island after sailing -
>
>   *wonderful guidance*
>
>   'The third day after, on the end of the rod—
>
>   *deed of power* —
>
>   The chieftain found— *it was a very great joy* -
>
>   a cluster of apples.'

Comment: Perhaps a fuller version of what Joyce was talking about is at https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page%3AEnglish_as_we_speak_it_in_Ireland_-_Joyce.djvu/69

Comment: Please identify the chevilles in your second quote.